# Hilbert scheme of points of complex surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic surface over $\mathbb{C}$ i.e a smooth and connected scheme of finite type over $\operatorname{spec}(\mathbb{C})$ of dimension $=2$. I denote with $X^{[n]}$ the Hilbert scheme of $0$-dimensional subscheme of length $=n$. This is known to be a smooth scheme of dim$=2n$ which moreover admits the Hilbert-Chow morphism: $$\chi:X^{[n]} \to X^{(n)} $$ where $X^{(n)}=X \times \cdots X/S_n$ is the symmetric product.

Among the properties of $\chi$ it is frequently stated that this morphism restricts to a fiber bundle (in the analytic topology) when considering $$\chi^{-1}(X) \rightarrow X $$ where $X \hookrightarrow X^{(n)} $ via the diagonal embedding. If I got it correctly the idea should be that every fibre $\chi^{-1}(x) \in \chi^{-1}(X)$ is isomorphic to the punctual Hilbert scheme and one would use this to obtain the property.

I was not able however to actually describe  explicit trivialization maps neither to get which open subsets to use in the trivializing cover nor why one should use the analytic and not the Zariski topology. Moreover, is there an analogous statement over other algebraically closed field where the world analytic is substituted by etale?

Comment: Try this definition [Hilbert_scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_scheme). Specially the section universality. This deals with [algebraic cycles chow spaces and hilbert chow morphisms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277769/algebraic-cycles-chow-spaces-and-hilbert-chow-morphisms). This give some (diagonal+embedding)[https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=diagonal+embedding]. [Trivialization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145482/local-trivializations-of-the-non-trivial-su2-bundle-over-s5)

Comment: [zariski open sets are dense in analytic topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15569/zariski-open-sets-are-dense-in-analytic-topology) and [etale algebraically closed field](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=etale+algebraically+closed+field)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to get how to locally trivialize the map after looking at those answers. Is there an intuitive way to understand the local triviality?

Comment: Not sure what the previous commenter was doing; link spamming is not good commenting and suspiciously their previous posts are all on calculus questions and similar level.

Comment: But here's a non-spam link that might be of interest: https://indigo.uic.edu/articles/thesis/Effective_Divisors_on_Kontsevich_Moduli_Spaces/10783163/1 In my thesis I (rather trivially) trivialized the Kontsevich space (which is isotrivial over projective space) in order to compute the Picard group of the fibers of the evaluation map. If I understand your question correctly (in which case all fibers are isomorphic, the space of length $n$ structures on a smooth point in a surface) then the same idea should work; just use the standard cover of $\mathbb P^r$ for some projective embedding of $X$.

Comment: It seems actually to work to me: the only point which is non clear is that seems to be Zariksi open sets and not just in the analytic topology. This is actually stronger, but it just seems strange as all the references strongly emphasize the analytic part (without proving it ahaha).

Comment: Perhaps the following standard observation is useful --- any smooth scheme is etale-locally isomorphic to the affine space (to see this just embed a Zariski neighborhood of a point into an affine space, then a general projection to an affine space of the same dimension is regular at the point, hence is etale on a smaller neighborhood). Consequently, the morphism $\chi$ is etale-locally the same as the same morphism for $\mathbb{A}^2$, and the latter is a fiber bundle, e.g., because of the transitive group action.

Comment: Have a look at (Trivialization)[https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trivialization.html] and in (Vector_bundle)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle]

Comment: @Sasha I think more or less I understood the reduction to the affine plane case, but I do not manage actually to end up the proof. Also, this actually seems similar to what the other user suggested which seems still not using the etale/analytic topology but the Zariski one.  What am I missing?

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio: I am not sure I understand what the other user has suggested. I also don't know why you can't end up the proof. So, how can I tell what are you missing?

Comment: Sorry I was being super imprecise. Actually I think I've worked out the affine plane case ahahahah. Thank you in any case :)